# Tracking monthly call count per individual - MySQL or XML?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am trying to determine the best way to store a monthly call tally for around 43 personnel. The client wants to be able to view the data in several different ways - who has the most/least calls YTD, graphs of the top 10, change from the pervious year, etc.

I considered trying to continuously update an XML file for each year with each individual's name and monthly call tally but that would make it more challenging to extract different types of data than if I were to use MySQL.

If MySQL is the favorable choice, would it be best to store the data with a single row per year per person with a column in each for every month of the year? Or, every month, add a row with the year, month, and call tally?

Advice would be appreciated.

Here is a sample of the XML file that contains the data -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<report>
    <ReportHeader>
        <Section SectionNumber="0">
            <Picture Name="DeptPic1" GraphicType="BolbField"></Picture>
        </Section>
    </ReportHeader>
    <Group Level="1">
        <GroupFooter>
            <Section SectionNumber="1">
                <Field Name="Field11" FieldName="{IncdPers.PERSONNAME}">
                    <FormattedValue>Captain John Doe</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>Captain John Doe</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="Field12" FieldName="{IncdPers.PERSONLOOKUPID}">
                    <FormattedValue>Doe, John</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>Doe, John</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="Field13" FieldName="DistinctCount ({In5basic.GUIDIDNUMBER}, {IncdPers.PERSONLOOKUPID})">
                    <FormattedValue>6</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>6</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="Field14" FieldName="{@PercentInc}">
                    <FormattedValue>54.55</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>54.55</Value>
                </Field>
                <Text Name="Text14">
                    <TextValue>%</TextValue>
                </Text>
            </Section>
        </GroupFooter>
    </Group>
    <Group Level="1">
        <GroupFooter>
            <Section SectionNumber="1">
                <Field Name="Field11" FieldName="{IncdPers.PERSONNAME}">
                    <FormattedValue>Firefighter Jane Smith</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>Firefighter Jane Smith</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="Field12" FieldName="{IncdPers.PERSONLOOKUPID}">
                    <FormattedValue>Smith, Jane</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>Smith, Jane</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="Field13" FieldName="DistinctCount ({In5basic.GUIDIDNUMBER}, {IncdPers.PERSONLOOKUPID})">
                    <FormattedValue>1</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="Field14" FieldName="{@PercentInc}">
                    <FormattedValue>9.09</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>9.09</Value>
                </Field>
                <Text Name="Text14">
                    <TextValue>%</TextValue>
                </Text>
            </Section>
        </GroupFooter>
    </Group>
</report>
```

Comment: What purpose does XML serve here? Are you interfacing with another system?

Comment: Where and what is your source data?

Comment: Source data is actually an XML file, submitted by the client monthly. I use PHP to iterate over the data and extract each record by name and number of calls. I need to combine each month's XML data into a single data source for each year.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the xml file you'd be parsing?

Comment: Continuously updating an XML file is a recipe for disaster. It's not hard to use a database, and even a basic database like SQLite will give you capabilities that doing in pure XML is tedious or impossible.

Comment: Agreed, tadman.. I suppose the fact that the source data is in XML got me thinking "hmm, I've never actually generated XML in a project.." lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly the kind of thing relational databases are good at.  I would store the data at its most granular level - records of individual calls if you have it, if not then per user/month.  Having a column for each month will make it difficult to query.

If the data your receive is not raw call data, but some sort of monthly summary, store it in the db that way to give yourself the most flexibility when querying.

Comment: The data comes in monthly, with a total number of calls per person for that month. The source is an XML file in itself, I just want to find the best way to keep all of the data in one central location (rather than a bunch of individual XML files) and so that I can work with it

Comment: +1. Just pull in the XML data as is, then you can transform it any way you want. The amount of data you will have sounds negligible. Store one row per call, if you can.

Comment: By one row per call do you mean the total number of calls for that month? Because these numbers are not being entered realtime, they are entered monthly with the total number of calls for that month.

Comment: one row per call assumed that you were dealing with raw call data - you weren't very specific in your original question.

Comment: Ah right you are, sorry about that. See updated question for XML example

Comment: regardless, store the data at whatever resolution you get it, that will give you the most flexibility to query.

Answer (score 2):

I'd have two tables. The first would simply be about the individual making the calls. The second table would be about the calls that person made. Like this:

```
Table 1
-------
+----------------+
| id        name |
+----------------+
  0         bob
  1         john
  2         mary



Table 2
-------
+----------------------------------------------+
| id        user_id     calls       date       |
+----------------------------------------------+
  0         0           12          2012-10-21
  1         1           15          2012-10-21
  2         2           23          2012-10-21
  3         0           16          2012-10-22
  4         1           17          2012-10-22
  5         2           28          2012-10-22
```

As you can see, you can use MySQL to store daily call info, or whatever interval you want. You can track numbers in any given time period (the example above shows only 2 days, though), generate reports off those numbers, show trends over time, etc.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. The numbers will be updated monthly, not daily - still best to store with timestamp format? For example, just use `2012-10-01`, `2012-11-01`, etc?

Comment: I don't see why not. MySQL allows you do stuff like `SELECT * FROM Table_2 WHERE date > 2012-09-01` which would show you all calls made after September, assuming you entered all the information on the first. If you entered it in on September 2nd, it'd be displayed. I think you get it though.

Comment: For a date range: `SELECT * FROM Table_2 WHERE date >= 2012-01-01 AND date <= 2102-03-01` That'd be the first quarter of 2012, for example.